# Unable to start SSH Service when running docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm in a development on my personal project. I have a master image using ubuntu:latest.

I have install everything including the OpenSSH server. When I try to "Service SSH Start" as a WWW-data user, it couldn't start the SSH service. See my configuration below.

sshd_config

```
Port            2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


#Copy Entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /home/

# # # # Start and enable SSH
   RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
       && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
       && echo "root:<somepassword>" | chpasswd \
       && chmod u+x /home/entrypoint.sh  

COPY /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/

EXPOSE 8000 2222

ENTRYPOINT [ "/home/entrypoint.sh" ]

# Change current user to www-data
USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
service ssh start
exec "$@"
```

and I'm getting below error

```
2023-05-25 16:30:02 start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 0 (Operation not permitted)
2023-05-25 16:30:02  * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd
2023-05-25 16:30:02    ...fail!
```

my question is, how can I start the ssh service by using www-data user?

Comment: You should start by explaining why you need systemctl/service inside a docker container more specifically to launch sshd. These are both bad ideas unless you are in particular situation (like testing using a container as a VM). To me it looks like you are in an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info). Using systemd inside a container has prerequisites (installing plethora of requirements in the image, running init as pid 1, mounting special volumes....). Accessing a container via ssh is globally non sense. And in all cases, even with justification, this is not a production setup.

Comment: Since you are new here, if you intend to give more info, please do not reply in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: To answer your very last question, you can't start sshd as a non-root user, you must be root.  In the same way you couldn't ssh into a PHP program running directly on the host, I also wouldn't worry about trying to configure an sshd here (with correctly managed host keys, a password not recorded in plain text in the image, ...).